# In MUI v5, how to make all element the same height and align vertically?

Tags: material-ui

I am learning material-ui v5 and it's new styling system, using sx, how do I set a bunch of different element on the same line to have the same height?

```
<Mui.Box m={2}
    component="form"
    sx={12}
    md={12}
    noValidate
    autoComplete="off"
    >
    <Mui.Card variant="outlined" raised sx={{ p: 2 }}>
        <Mui.Grid container  
            spacing={2}
            direction="row"
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="center">

                <Mui.Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
                    <Mui.TextField
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        id="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        defaultValue=""
                        helperText="Some important text"
                        />
                </Mui.Grid>
                <Mui.Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
                    <Mui.Button 
                        fullWidth 
                        variant="contained"
                            size="large">
                                Authenticate
                    </Mui.Button>
                </Mui.Grid>
        </Mui.Grid>
    </Mui.Card>
</Mui.Box>
```

Here is what it currently look like:

[image]

As you can see they have different height and are not aligned vertically, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hover the grid items and you'll notice that the `alignItems="center"` is possibly starting you at a bad spot.

Change this to `top` then you know the elements are starting at the same spot. Seeing as you have the `helperText`, I think the best option is to then set your button height to match the `TextField`.

So, change the grid container prop `alignItems="center"` to `alignItems="top"` and then add something like `sx={{ height: "56px" }}` to your button.

[image]

If you need to do this frequently, make the button a styled component so you don't need to keep adding the `sx` prop.

See it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-forked-tn7rw?file=/index.js

By the way, line 3 looks like it should be xs, not sx.

Comment: Looks great!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the height of the text box and the button precisely enough in MUI to make them exactly the same height, the "large" button is just slightly larger than a "small" text field.

But you can at least align them better by using `alignItems="stretch"` in the outer `<Mui.Grid>`:

[image: Top alignment with "stretch"]

But, in general it's much better to organize forms vertically, in a single column:

> Single column forms convert a lot be!er than multi-column ones because you only have a single path to follow with your eyes, instead of jumping between blocks.